# How to use sed to modify last 2 digit of a line when a string matches in a file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

i have a file 'a.txt' which have a content:

```
K8A2-19C204-BA109691  
ML_18.10.4-109691
```

How can i search for a string say "ML_" in the file  and if it matches modify last 2 digit of that line say 91 to 00 using 'sed' command in bash script

Could you please help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `sed -E '/ML_/s/[0-9]{2}$/00/' file`

Comment: Thankyou anubhava it worked :)

Comment: could you please explain what "[0-9]{2}$" does?.Thanks in advance

Comment: @Deepak see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-regular-expressions and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/ML_/ && substr($0,length($0)-1)~/[0-9]+/{print substr($0,1,length($0)-1) "00";next} 1'   Input_file
```

In case you want to save the output into same Input_file then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file` to above code too.

***Solution 2nd:***

```
sed '/ML_/s/[0-9][0-9]$/00/'   Input_file
```

Use `sed -i` option in above `sed` command in case you want to save output into same Input_file itself.

***Explanation:***

`/ML_/`: Search string `ML_` here in each line and do following actions in case if it is present on the current line.

`s/`: `s` stands for substitute, do the substitute operation.

`[0-9][0-9]$/`: `[0-9][0-9]$` means any 2 digits at last `$` of the current line should be changed.

`00/`: Change above 2 digits with `00` in current line which has string `ML_` in it.

`Input_file`: Mentioning the Input_file here.

Comment: Thankyou for the information.If i get the solution with sed command it will be helpful.

Comment: @Deepak, please check my Solution 2nd and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Could you explain me what "[0-9][0-9]$" does.And i wan to play around "sed",any link  you can provide which is helpful?

Comment: @Deepak, I have updated my answer with my explanation now, also for `sed` you could read it with man page, basic books and you could learn on SO also(there are lot of stuff here related to here).